# Using Alamofire and Objectmapper the integer value always zero

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using Alamofire with ObjectMapper and my model class is like that

```
class Category: Object, Mappable {

dynamic var id: Int = 0
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var thumbnail = ""
var children = List<Category>()


override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}


required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    thumbnail <- map["thumbnail"]
    children <- map["children"]
}
```

}

and I am using Alamofire like that

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseArray { (response: Response<[Category], NSError>) in

        let categories = response.result.value

        if let categories = categories {
            for category in categories {
                print(category.id)
                print(category.name)
            }
        }
    }
```

the id is always zero, I don't know why?

Comment: Does the "id" field exist in the JSON file? If it does not, your initial value of zero will remain. Is the value in quotes in the JSON file? If it is, then it's a string. I don't know if ObjectMapper will convert it to Int.

Comment: yes "id" exists in JSON file

Comment: you are right the value of "id" in quotes in JSON file if I removed the quotes it can map the value.   Thanks @BobWakefield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the "id" field exist in the JSON file? If it does not, your initial value of zero will remain. Is the value in quotes in the JSON file? If it is, then it's a string. I don't know if ObjectMapper will convert it to Int.

Moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed it by adding transformation in the mapping function in model class like that

```
id <- (map["id"], TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { Int($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { String($0) } }))
```

thanks to @BobWakefield

Comment: I added my comment to an answer. Can you change the correct answer so I get credit for it? Thanks.

Comment: i used it for int in json to string in object parsing, but i am not able to get rid of Optional()